# Cert-Manager: Challenge stuck on presenting

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, portforwarding, cert-manager

I want to set up TLS on my microk8s kubernetes setup on Ubuntu 20.04.
This has worked in the past, but after switching to microk8s 1.28 and cert-manager 1.13, I am stuck.

I always get  `Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request`.
Furthermore, the challenge description says `dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:80: connect: connection refused`.

```
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: ...
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          name: whoami
```

For the ingress-type, I tried name, class, and also ingressClassName as mentioned in the [docs](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/http01/). Problem is always the same.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: whoami
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: whoami
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: whoami
        image: containous/whoami
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: whoami
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whoami
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: whoami
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.domain.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod
```

The ACME-solver pod gets created, but what I noticed was the listening port being 8089 for whatever reason.
The service also listens on this port:

```
cm-acme-http-solver-h648p   NodePort    10.152.183.48   <none>        8089:30571/TCP   15m
```

Shouldn't this be 80, as my server is not exposing port 8089?

Comment: The port on which something is listening in a Pod generally has nothing to do with the port on which you access the service externally; that is typically controlled by an Ingress resource (or by directly accessing an exposed NodePort).

Comment: So the exposed NodePort is 8089, but why is the challenge trying to access through 80, where it gets a connection refused (which I can reproduce with curl).

Comment: When solving HTTP-01 challenges, I believe cert-manager creates a temporary ingress matching the hostname and port of the target ingress.

Comment: Yes, when using ingressNameClass. I get `my.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/D-bbwsQUZLQxSRfE1EKMiSOGIqlqZN60n90YQjBu_U8   cm-acme-http-solver-2jwpv:8089 (10.1.20.17:8089)`. But `curl 10.1.20.17:8089/.well-known/acme-challenge/D-bbwsQUZLQxSRfE1EKMiSOGIqlqZN60n90YQjBu_U8` gives a 404.

Comment: There's nothing in your configuration suggesting that port 8089 should ever be externally accessible.

Comment: Sorry, had a typo there. I was using port 80, `curl 10.1.20.17:80/.well-known/acme-challenge/D-bbwsQUZLQxSRfE1EKMiSOGIqlqZN60n90YQjBu_U8` can reproduce the `Failed to connect to 10.1.20.17 port 80: Connection refused`. When trying the service IP `10.152.183.212` instead, the curl just seems to be stucked.  It just hangs after `TCP_NODELAY set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had cert-manager v1.13.2 installed via their [manifest directly from github](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/tag/v1.13.2). Going back to the stable version using `microk8s enable cert-manager` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the [docs](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/http01/#ingressclassname), try to follow the `issuer` YAML file that uses the `ingressClassName` rather than the name:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: example-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: example-issuer-account-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          ingressClassName: nginx
```

This should forward the request to the backend service of your app from the port of ingress-nginx exposed externally.